# facebook- wordpress post not showing pictures on fb link

Tags: facebook, wordpress, image

am trying to add a post, copying a link of a page on my website. some pages images shows as you can see on the image, but other pages no images come up, when i need it too. any reason why, as you can see the 2st link has no image, but on the 3rd post there is an image...

However when i add another link it shows nothing expect the text..

[image]

so how can I share a link on facebook and show images from the page ,,, I don't understand

When i share this page on facebook no images:
http://www.dravet.org.uk/2014/03/the-ollie-johnson-memorial-fund-for-dravet-syndrome-uk/

However when i share this page, it shows a image:

http://www.dravet.org.uk/family-support/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress, everytime you post a post, there is a section called "Featured Image", try to upload image to  Featured image section, then share again, you should see it.

Comment: When i share this page on facebook no images: http://www.dravet.org.uk/2014/03/the-ollie-johnson-memorial-fund-for-dravet-syndrome-uk/

However when i share this page, it shows a image:

http://www.dravet.org.uk/family-support/

Comment: This is usually due to the featured image or uploaded image not meeting Facebook’s size requirements, which are:

At least 200×200 pixels in both width and height
Aspect ratio of width and height no greater than 3; in other words, the width can’t be more than three times more than the height, and vice versa. An image such as the garden image below is too disproportionate for Facebook to use (300 pixels wide by 90 pixels high).

Comment: So try to adjust your picture's size, change to another picture, maybe the same width and height of the shown one. Just to see if that's the problem.

Comment: ok for some reason it works now. everything is the same!!! why!!!!! i have done no changes!!!!